# Solve $\min_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{R}}\left\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\right\|_{\mathbf{R}}^2$ s.t. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$; $\mathbf{R}\succeq0$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Dear optimization experts,

Do you have a suggestion how to solve this problem?

\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{R}, \mathbf{\lambda}}  f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{R}) 
&= \left\| \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x} \right\|_{\mathbf{R}}^2 + \mathbf{\lambda}^T \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}  \\
&= \left( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}  \right)^T \mathbf{R} \left( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}  \right) + \mathbf{\lambda}^T \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x},
\end{align} 
where $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ is given, $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and $\mathbf{\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ is a *Lagrange Multiplier*, and $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is given.

If it is dependent on a single variable (and Lagrange multiplier), that is either $\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathbf{R}$, then it can be solved in closed-form. But I am not sure how to do it for more than one variable jointly, in this case. Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

Original constrained optimization problem
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize}_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{R}} \quad \ & \left( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}  \right)^T \mathbf{R} \left( \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}  \right) \\
\text{subject to }\quad & \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} 
\end{align*}

EDIT EDIT:
$\mathbf{R} \succeq 0$ is positive semi-definite (constraint).

---

If $\mathbf{R}$ is fixed and invertible (so it should be positive definite to be on safe side), then I can show that (also suggested by Amrit P.)
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y} - \left(\mathbf{R} + \mathbf{R}^T \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{\lambda} \ ,
\end{align}
and $\mathbf{\lambda}$ can be obtained by plugging $\mathbf{x}$ to the constraint 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \ ,
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\lambda} = \left(\mathbf{A} \left(\mathbf{R} + \mathbf{R}^T \right)^{-1}  \mathbf{A}^T \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \ .
\end{align}

---

I am still thinking, what if we want to find optimal $\mathbf{R}$ as well... perhaps I am hitting the wall :( ...

I saw a paper that also obtain $R$ but not jointly .... e.g., cf. R. Kumar and A. Tyagi, "Weighted Least Squares Based Spectral Precoder for OFDM Cognitive Radio", in IEEE Wireless Comm. Letters, Dec. 2015.

Comment: No, I meant, what I wrote there. it is like a weighted least-squares.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. It seems that if $A \neq 0$ then the minimum (infimum) is $-\infty$.

Comment: If $R$ is given, then the problem is constrained weighted least-squares. The solution can be obtained in analytical form. Agree? If optimal $R$ needs to be found jointly with $x$, then how to do it?

Comment: I'm assuming you want $R \succeq 0$ to be positive semidefinite? Otherwise $\|\cdot\|_R$ isn't a norm.

Comment: Take $x=0$ and $R=-tI$, $t\to+\infty$ to get the objective $-t|y|^2\to-\infty$ (assuming $y\ne 0$).

Comment: As stated the minimization is obviously unbounded, so the question really makes no sense.  It would be best for the OP to backup a step or two and explain where this problem came from.

Comment: Please note that $\mathbf{R} \succeq 0$ is a positive semidefinite. I apologize for missing that constraint.

Comment: @user550103 now that constraint makes a whole lot of difference.

Comment: For the original constrained problem, since $R \succeq 0$, we obviously have $(y-x)^TR(y-x) \ge 0$. Equality is trivially achieved by picking $R = 0$, $x = 0$, so the minimum is trivially $0$. Are you sure $R$ isn't fixed?

Comment: If $R$ is fixed, then the solution is straightforward. I was just wondering if $R$ is not fixed, then do we have any solution? I have seen some papers that try to compute $R$ iteratively via some Lawson algorithm, but I didn't understand the whole details yet, must admit.

Comment: or can we do something like coordinate ascent, i.e., fixed $R$ then solve for $x$ and then for a given $x$ solve for $R$? does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $R$ is a variable in this optimization? Without that condition, it's a relatively straightforward problem.

Since you have already made the constraint a part of the optimization objective, we can take partial derivatives wrt variables of the problem ($x,R,\lambda$), and set them to zero for obtaining the optimal point.

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,R,\lambda)}}{\partial x}=-(y-x)^T(R+R^T)+\lambda^TA=0\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,R,\lambda)}}{\partial R}=(y-x)(y-x)^T=0\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,R,\lambda)}}{\partial\lambda}=x^TA=0\tag{3}$$

Equation $2$ suggests that $x=y$, which makes sense since that would immediately set the positive part of the objective to $0$.

Equation $3$ suggests that $x$ should lie in the null-space of $A^T$. Combining equations $2$ and $3$ tells us that an optimal solution exists only if $y$ belongs to the null space of $A^T$:

$$y=\sum_ic_ia_i^{\perp}=A^{\perp}c$$

where $a_i^{\perp}$ is the column vector of $A^{\perp}:A^TA^{\perp}=0$.

Now let's consider the case where the above is not true, i.e.

$$y=A^{\perp}c+v:v=Ad\neq0$$

In such a case, if you were to run the above through a convex optimizer, you would end up with-

$$x=y+\epsilon:A(v+\epsilon)=0$$

$$\min_{\epsilon,R,\lambda}\epsilon^TR\epsilon+\lambda^T(Av+A\epsilon)$$

$$\implies 2R\epsilon+A^T\lambda=0\Leftrightarrow\epsilon=-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}A^T\lambda$$

$$A\epsilon=-Av\Leftrightarrow AR^{-1}A^T\lambda=2Av$$

We can calculate $\lambda$ and $\epsilon$ uniquely if $AR^{-1}A^T$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To be candid, $\mathbf{R}$ is kind of fixed, but adapted outside the weighted constrained least squares (WCLS) solution. In other words, imagine iteration cycles with adaptive weights $\mathbf{R}$, where within each iteration cycle, some papers compute the WCLS solution for the given weight matrix $\mathbf{R}$. So, I was thinking, why one can not optimize both $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{x}$, jointly. But according to the feedback I receive, it seems that this posed problem does not make sense.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt. So, I will 'like' your answer